# Using (UIView) classes non-programmatically - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, uiview

So I have created a few of classes which are subclasses of `UIView`. Let's say I have a class called "ExampleClass". I thought that I could use that class by creating a UIView and setting its class to "ExampleClass" under the Identity-tab. However, whenever I do this I'll get an error saying;

```
fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file /Users/[My Name]/Desktop/xcode/[Project Name]/ExampleClass/ViewController.swift, line [n]
```

When I create a similar View programmatically by saying:

```
let MyView = ExampleClass
MyView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 400)
```

I do not get this error.

---

The class does contain the required init, which is the cause of this error:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: simply call `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` in the init

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem? If not, what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `super.init(coder: aDecoder) inside your`init` function

Comment: Yes, just as luk2302 said! Thx!